# Read file - line by line to create permutations in c

Tags: c, io, permutation

So I'm having issues attempting to read a text file consisting of three lines. I am trying to read each line and create permutations per line. I want to continue looping through doing this to every line until I hit EOF. I'm trying to implement fgets within the while loop in my main. Am I on the right track? The main issue I am having is passing a char to my permutation method in my main.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(char *x, char *y)
{
    char tempVariable;

    tempVariable = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = tempVariable;
}

void stringPermutation(char *a, int zeroVariable, int factorial)
{
    int i;

    if(zeroVariable == factorial)
    {
        printf("%s\n", a);
    }
    else
    {
        for(i = zeroVariable; i <= factorial; i++)
        {
            swap((a + zeroVariable), (a + i));
            stringPermutation(a, zeroVariable + 1, factorial);
            swap((a + zeroVariable), (a + i));
            }
        }
    }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    if(argc != 2)
    {       
        printf("ERROR - WRONG AMOUNT OF ARGUMENTS\n");

    }
     else
    {   
        FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        int x;

        printf("PERMUTATIONS:\n");

        while((x = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
        {   
            stringPermutation(x, 0, x - 1); //I'm messing up here
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, you're passing a `char` where a `char*` is expected. Your compiler should have told you that...

Comment: I understand that int x is being passed into a parameter that needs to be a char... i guess my question is... how do I turn that int into a char? cast it? i've been reading that fgets reads line by line, however, it stops at \n or EOF..?

Comment: try `char x[] = "abc"; stringPermutation(x, 0, stelen(x)-1);`

Comment: Thanks for the tips BLUEPIXY... I can see how that would work but what if I need to read from a file rather than hard code it like you did?

Comment: `char x[256]; while(fgets(x, sizeof x, file)){ x[strcspn(x, "\n")]=0; stringPermutation(x, 0, strlen(x)-1); }`

Comment: Oh my good lord, that works.... I'm going to look into strcspn and see how that routine works. I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stringPermutation()` is expecting a `char*` not a `char` or an `int`. 
You are passing a `char`. It looks like `stringPermutation` is using the parameter as a `char*` too and so in this case the caller is wrong.

Looks like you need to read a few chars into a buffer and pass the buffer to `stringPermutation()`. More simply use `fgets` or `getline` etc to read a string in one call instead of building it char by char yourself.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out. I'll try what you said and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

```
stringPermutation(x, 0, x - 1);
```

`x` is of type `int`, gets ASCII code of `char` as value but the function `stringPermutation` expects `char *a`

I suggest using [fgets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgetc.htm) for reading lines of a file.

Comment: I'm getting the impression I need to use fgets... thank you